# Appending a circle to an svg using javascript called by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, svg

I have been searching for an answer that will work and have been unable to find one.
I have a game map that I am using for an RP guild. I am using the map to display influence which we hold in that game's world. I have no issue displaying the map if I have it all coming through in echo statements in php, however, what I would like to do is only have the influence areas draw on the map as pulled from the database.

I have the following function which works when called from within my .js file:

```
function drawInfluence(id, x, y, inf, dis) {
    svg = document.getElementById("small_map");
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    var c = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    c.setAttribute('id',"c"+id);
    c.setAttribute('r',"15");
    c.setAttribute('cx',pt.x);
    c.setAttribute('cy',pt.y);
    c.setAttribute('fill',inf);
    c.setAttribute('stroke-width','5');
    c.setAttribute('stroke',dis);
    svg.appendChild(c);
}
```

This function works perfect if I call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#small_map").load( function() {
         drawInfluence(1, 150, 150, "red", "blue");
    });
});
```

However, if I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#small_map").load( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/inf_map_load.php',
            success: function () {
                // There is nothing to do here right now
            }
        });
    });
});
```

with a PHP file that looks like:

```
<?php
echo'   drawInfluence(1, 150, 150, "red", "blue");';
?>
```

or like

```
<?php
echo'   <script type="text/javascript">drawInfluence(1, 150, 150, "red", "blue");</script>';
?>
```

I receive no output at all.

The function is in my .JS file along with my other JQuery callbacks for other functions (which are working perfectly fine.)

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#small_map").load( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/inf_map_load.php',
            success: function () {
                alert("Testing");
                drawInfluence(1, 150, 150, "red", "blue");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the circle will draw where it's supposed to as well as the alert popping up I can't use the drawInfluence from this area though because the end goal is to have the the information for the javascript call to be read from a database which contains multiple rows of data which will each have a unique identifier for hover and click events. Writing the entire document using php echo statements works, but is not the most efficient and I would prefer to use callbacks rather than inline svg javascript.

Comment: You should provide correct code. `<script type="text\javascript>`. This line has at least two errors. You need a forward slash instead of a backslash and quotes are not closed.

Comment: I made that correction and retried it (I've been playing with this code for hours today so missed that in my typing it above) and still no output at all.

Comment: have you tried the jquery loadscript function on the url...and then the php will not have the <script> tags but be treated as a .js file

Comment: I am not familiar with loadscript but after looking at it, it appears to be a simpler version of getscript which will not parse the PHP properly allowing it to retrieve and loop through the database rows.

It's also possible that I'm missing something here as I'm still pretty new to jQuery as I haven't written any real code in almost 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it some more I found that placing an empty div tag with an id and using the following code I was able to get the script to do what I wanted though it draws the influence areas before the map finishes loading. Not a big issue but not aesthetically pleasing either.

In my .JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map_load").load("scripts/inf_map_load.php");
});
```

My PHP file

```
<?php
echo'<script type="text/javascript">drawInfluence(1, 150, 150, "red", "blue")';
?>
```

And the empty div which made it work

```
<div id="map_load"></div>
```

I still don't know if this was the best way to do what I needed, but it's working now and that was more important at the moment. Appreciate the replies I did get.